# vsftpd include configuration from another file

Tags: configuration, vsftpd

I tried configuring vsftpd and was able to configure it successfully.

Is there any option to "include" configuration from another file inside /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf?

I tried looking at the man page and all I could find was specifying user specific configuration using `user_config_dir`

I am using `anonymous` login and I am not sure whether I can use `user_config_dir` for anonymous login.

```
# vsftpd -v
vsftpd: version 2.2.2
```

Comment: @msp9011: i get the error `500 OOPS: missing value in config file for: source /etc/vsftpd/config/common.conf`

Answer (score 1):

If the native tool does not support file inclusion, you could use [`m4`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/m4.html).

To show a *simplified* example, here are two input files:

**vsftpd.conf.m4**

```
# line one is a comment
anonymous_enable=YES
include(`includeme.m4')dnl
```

**includeme.m4**

```
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

Given those two files in your current directory, execute `m4 vsftpd.conf.m4 > vsftpd.conf` to generate this vsftpd.conf file:

```
# line one is a comment
anonymous_enable=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

There is a rather large manual for m4; see `info m4` or the [GNU M4 web manual](http://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/m4/manual/m4-1.4.18/index.html) for more.

The only feature I'm using to accomplish file inclusion here is the `include` macro. The syntax (without changing the default quoting characters) requires a backtick and single quote to surround the filename that you want to include. The `dnl` token at the end tells `m4` that you don't want it to print a newline after processing the statement.

Managing the file this way means that you need to take care to update the m4 files instead of the `vsftpd.conf` file. You could add a `README` file to the directory with a warning; I've also seen people use a `Makefile` with a recipe to generate the config file with a simple `make` command. The presence of either file might give the administrator pause enough to review them. You might also include a header in the vsftpd.conf.m4 file saying something like:

> "# This file was generated with m4 -- edit vsftpd.conf.m4 instead!"

as yet another alert.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The problem for me is that vsftpd.conf is owned by `root` and i don't want to gain `root` privilege to modify the file. Hence if there is a way to include another file that is not owned by `root`, i can place frequently changing configurations in that file and can modify without `root` privilege.

Comment: Then this gets into gross work-around territory, but my initial thought would be to schedule a (root-owned) cron job that generates the config file as often as you like. Place the "includeme.m4" file anywhere that you have editing permissions and then point the vsftpd.conf.m4 file to that location.